# How to tell YUI compressor maven plugin to output to WAR file and/or source directories?

Tags: maven, yui, m2e, yui-compressor

I'm trying to add YUI compressor to my JSF eclipse maven project. I'm not a maven professional, I just use the m2e maven plugin to resolve my dependencies and to right click my project und export it to a `.WAR` file. At this point, the YUI compressor plugin is working and compresses all css and javascript files as soon as I change and save a resource (i.e. a html file). My problem is, that it's neither putting the compressed files back to `MyProject/src/main/webapp/resources/css|js` nor into the resulting `.WAR` file. It puts them into `MyProject/target/app-0.01-SNAPSHOT/resources/css|js` which seems to be of no (?) use. How can I set it up to put the files into the `.WAR` file **and** into the original input-directories (so i can see and include them in my html files)? I have read a couple of threads here, but couldn't find the solution.

Here is the relevant part from my `pom.xml`:

```
<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compress</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <!-- I was playing around with this. At this point, the following does the same as the default
            setting, i.e. putting the files into the /target/ directory, which is not what i want/need. -->
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/js</sourceDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/resources/js</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>yuicompressor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.3.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compress</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute>
                                        <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                                    </execute>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

</build>
```